# Macro to retrieve [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I find myself calling `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]` so often that I would really like to make a macro along the lines of winSize(). Where might be a good place to tuck this into Cocos2D's libraries? Initially I thought the Support>CGPointExtension.h might work, but at that location ccdirector is not defined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
#define WINSIZE [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
```

Personally I wouldn't use a macro for this, a better alternative is to add an ivar or static var to the class where you need winSize frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I typically put these definitions in a .m/.h, per project. For exampld, in the .h

```
extern float  kScreenWidth;                  // design width of the app (in points)
extern float  kScreenHeight;                 // design height of the app (in points)
extern CGSize kBattleMidPoint;
extern float  kLongTouch;
extern float  kTileWidth;
extern float  kTileHeight;
```

in the .m

```
float  kScreenWidth  = 480.0;
float  kScreenHeight = 320.0;
CGSize kBattleMidPoint;
float  kLongTouch    = .65f;
float  kTileWidth    = 40.;
float  kTileHeight   = 40.;
```

and also somewhere in the .m setters to override the above defaults. I call them once, just after CCDirector is initialized.

```
+ (void)setScreenWidth:(float)screenWidth {

    kScreenWidth = screenWidth;
    if (screenWidth >= 568.0) {
        kDeviceType = deviceTypeIpodTall;
    }
}

+ (void)setScreenHeight:(float)screenHeight {

    kScreenHeight = screenHeight;
}   

+ (void)setBattleMidPoint:(CGSize)midPoint {

    kBattleMidPoint = midPoint;
}

+ (void)setTileWidth:(float)tileWidth {

    kTileWidth = tileWidth;
}

+ (void)setTileHeight:(float)tileHeight {

    kTileHeight = tileHeight;
}
```

and finally, i include the .h in my precompiled headers. I tend to avoid (at all possible costs) to modify / extend the cocos2d code base, reserving the right to update at minimal work effort :).

Comment: That certainly is one way to do it. I was hoping for something a little less verbose, and more akin to universal development. Nevertheless, it's something to think about– thanks.

Comment: lol ... well, i'm not in the business of building and shipping frameworks. This works well for our team. But nothing beats sprite.position=ccp(kScreenWidth/2,kScreenHeight/2); anywhere in the code base, it is as terse as it gets. :)